# How can I use Azure Mobile Services and SQL Azure StoredProc function in my WP 8.1 App for user registration page

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-sql-database

I have been following the online tutorials provides on Azure and WP series. So far I have been able to understand flow of "TODO application" which is built.

I followed the guidelines provided and created my own WP 8.1 "User registration app". I have created the following in Azure.

1. Mobile Service
2. Database and required tables and required columns for this application
3. I have also written StoredProc which provides OUTPUT result upon success and failure.

When I tried to call this storedproc I was not able to access or to be more honest, I don't have any idea on how to call this or go about. I have been looking around places which were pointing to use "Mobile service API" then call the StoredProc function etc which made me more confused.

How to solve this?

What I need to achieve is, from the WP app I have written, the user key-in the required values, click on "register" button, the function should call Storedproc by passing all the values from WP app to StoredProc as parameter, upon successful execution of StoredProc, it returns a RESULT value which my application need to use and save a system generated value in WP isolated storage, so when next time application loads, it will check for this file, if available the application loads if not it will navigate the user to registration page.

I have been able to pull out sample on isolated storage and other stuff, but not able to achieve with respect to StoredProc and sending and receiving the data to and from Azure SQL Server.

Please help - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which sort of Mobile Services backend you have (Node or C#) you can invoke stored procedures using a pattern similar to the following:

```
function(request, response) {
  var mssql = request.service.mssql;
  mssql.query("EXEC <<your_sproc_name>> ?", request.query.<<your_query_prop_here>>, {
    success: function(results) {
      // console.log(results) <-- use for debugging
      // return results (or pass to another function)
    }
 });
};
```

If this doesn't really answer the question fully it's worth looking at the [Azure Mobile Services Custom APIs documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn280974.aspx) which will cover this scenario in more detail.